# I want to Disable Focus on Main JFrame, when I try to click on it after opening the 2nd JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

[image]

This Image represent the 1st/Main Frame and the 2nd Frame.The 2nd frame will open when I click on "Review Order" Button. After it's opened i want to disable focus on the main frame so the user won't able to access the main frame until he/she close the 2ndframe.

Comment: Don't use two frames. An application should only have a single JFrame. In this case for you second window you can use a `modal JDialog`. A modal JDialog will give focus to the dialog and you won't be able to access the frame until the dialog is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
mainFrame.setEnabled(false);
```

in order to make the Main Frame ignore user input.

Later, when the user is allowed to access the Main Frame, re-enable it by calling:

```
mainFrame.setEnabled(true);
```